# codeigniter 4 / how to select emoji from mysql db and display in view

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I have a table called mh_country.  Here is one row from phpmyadmin.  You can see that emoji correctly displays the flag of Afghanistan.

[image: snapshot of database to get emoji]

The encoding in mysql of 'emoji' is correct and is as follows;

[image: mysql structure of emoji]

I would like to display the emoji in my view.  First of all, here is my method to get 'emoji':

```
function display_country_dialing_codes(){
    $model = new \App\Models\MhCountryModel;
    $builder = $model->builder('mh_country');
    $builder->select('country_name, phonecode, emoji');
    $query   = $builder->get();
    $result  = $query->getResult();
    return $result;
}
```

Now I am trying to display the flag in my view with;

```
            $x = display_country_dialing_codes();
            echo $x[0]->emoji;
```

but all I get is '??'.

How can I display the emoji flag please?

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

As of Jan 2022 browsers except Firefox do not support country flag emojis. Most of the other emojis are displayed properly.

**Original Answer**

Tested and it works

[image]

Edit your database config file

```
app\Config\Database.php
```

and set `charset` to `utf8mb4` under your database connection

```
'charset'  => 'utf8mb4',
```

Comment: Thank you Ergec.  I am getting closer.  Now I see the letters AF instead of ??  Curious how to display that as emoji though.

Comment: That is because not all browsers support country flag emojis. Only Firefox. Try a smiley face, you'll see it will work on all browsers.

Comment: Thank you and all well understood now. Thank you to all for helping me understand this.